# Finding parameters next to vectors to get a desired vector

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra

What is the simplest algorithm I can use to find such values of `m1, m2, m3, ..., mn`, that the following equation is satisified (of course to a certain accuracy threshold):

```
m1*v1 + m2*v2 + ... + mn*vn = vd
```

where `v1, v2, ..., vn` and `vd` are given vectors of 3-10 dimensions? The parameters `m1, ..., mn` should be positive real numbers.

I need an algorithm that's reliable and quick to code. Problem sizes will be small, (no larger than n=100) so speed isn't a very important issue, especially that the accuracies will be rather liberal.

Comment: This is "how do I solve Ax = b" (A = v1...vn packed horizontally into a matrix). There's linear algebra libraries in every mainstream language that can solve this.

Comment: should not it be `m1*v1+m2*v2+...mn*vn=vd` instead of `m1*v1+m2*v1+...mn*vn=vd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a [system of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations). You can write it as the following matrix equation:

```
A * x = b
```

Where, if `k` is the dimension of the vectors:

```
    / v1[1] v2[1] ... vn[1] \
    | v1[2] v2[2] ... vn[2] |
A = | ..................... |
    | ..................... |
    \ v1[k] v2[k] ... vn[k] /

     / m1 \
     | m2 |
 x = | .. |
     | .. |
     \ mn /

    / vd[1] \
    | vd[2] |
b = | ..... |
    | ..... |
    \ vd[k] /
```

There are several ways to solve these. If `n` is equal to `k` and the problem has a solution (which may or may not), then you can solve it by inverting the coefficient matrix `A` and computing `inverse(A) * b`, by using [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) or, most commonly, with [Gaussian elmination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). If `n` is not equal to `k`, several things can happen, you can learn about it googling a little bit.

By the way, you said that `m1 ... mn` must be positive numbers (non-zero?). In this case, you may want to approach your problem from [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), adding restrictions like `m1 > 0`, `m2 > 0`, etc. and using [simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) to solve it.

Whatever you use, is really not advisable to program the algorithm by yourself. There are plenty of libraries for every language that deal with this kind of problems.

Comment: Indeed, the simplex algorithm looks like it does exactly what I need, with an added bonus of maximizing a given function, which will actually come in handy. Thank you!